# Get IP address of Apple Watch

Tags: swift, ip-address, watchos

How to access IP address of Apple Watch programatically? I have used UIDevice extension in iOS for finding IP. This is an extension of UIDevice but which is not supported in watchOS what could be the other option?

```
extension UIDevice {

    private struct InterfaceNames {
        static let wifi = ["en0"]
        static let wired = ["en2", "en3", "en4"]
        static let cellular = ["pdp_ip0","pdp_ip1","pdp_ip2","pdp_ip3"]
        static let supported = wifi + wired + cellular
    }

    func ipAddress() -> String? {
        var ipAddress: String?
        var ifaddr: UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?

        if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
            var pointer = ifaddr

            while pointer != nil {
                defer { pointer = pointer?.pointee.ifa_next }

                guard
                    let interface = pointer?.pointee,
                    interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET) || interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_family == UInt8(AF_INET6),
                    let interfaceName = interface.ifa_name,
                    let interfaceNameFormatted = String(cString: interfaceName, encoding: .utf8),
                    InterfaceNames.supported.contains(interfaceNameFormatted)
                    else { continue }

                var hostname = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(NI_MAXHOST))

                getnameinfo(interface.ifa_addr,
                            socklen_t(interface.ifa_addr.pointee.sa_len),
                            &hostname,
                            socklen_t(hostname.count),
                            nil,
                            socklen_t(0),
                            NI_NUMERICHOST)

                guard
                    let formattedIpAddress = String(cString: hostname, encoding: .utf8),
                    !formattedIpAddress.isEmpty
                    else { continue }

                ipAddress = formattedIpAddress
                break
            }

            freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
        }

        return ipAddress
    }

}

 UIDevice.current.ipAddress()
```

How is this possible in watchOS

Comment: How's that `ipAddress` function defined? It's not a built-in UIKit function.

Comment: Does the function work as a stand-alone function? It doesn’t have to be an extension of UIDevice, that’s just a convenience