# How to retrieve IP address of Apple Watch programmatically in watchOS?

Tags: ip-address, ipv6, apple-watch, watchos, ipv4

I have been trying to find a way to retrieve the IP address of an Apple Watch running watchOS programmatically.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me through the process or provide an alternative solution to obtain the IP address of an Apple Watch programmatically.

I am developing an application that requires this information, and any help or insights would be highly valuable.

Thank you in advance!

I came across this Stack Overflow post ([Get IP address of Apple Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952536/get-ip-address-of-apple-watch)), which seems to be the only available reference on the topic.